# Ajax call after 10 second automatic inside a loop

Tags: ajax, loops

```
jQuery:
```

// Load  message
    (function loadAdmin() {

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'c_id=' + $(this).data('c_id') + '&offset=' + $(this).data('offset'), //'foo='+ bar+'&calibri='+ nolibri,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: $("#webroot").text() + 'chats/loadMsg',
            success: function (data) {
                var id = 0;
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    if (item.Chat.status == 'active') {
                        $('.temp_msg').remove();
                    }
                    if (!$('#' + item.Chat.id)[0]) {
                        if (item.Chat.admin_message) {
                            $('<div class="msg_a" id="' + item.Chat.id + '">' + item.Chat.admin_message + '</div>').insertBefore('.' + $(this).data('c_id') + ' .msg_push');
                        }
                        if (item.Chat.client_message) {
                            $('<div class="msg_b" id="' + item.Chat.id + '">' + item.Chat.client_message + '</div>').insertBefore('.' + $(this).data('c_id') + ' .msg_push');
                        }
                        $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
                    }
                    id = item.Chat.id;
                });
                $('.' + c_id + ' .msg_head').data('offset', id)
            },
            complete: function () {
                // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                setTimeout(loadAdmin, 10000);
            }
        });

})();
// END load message
```

I set c_id statically.This works fine. But I want to do this same action for all  *activated* class.

This is something like this:

```
$('.activated').each(function () {
    // do ajax call
loadAdmin();

});
```

Here crucial situation is for first iteration there start a recursion of  loadAdmin(); function calling, then again start first iteration and never step up to second iteration. How can I meet my situation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setInterval() function for complete your requirements.

Like this :

```
$('.activated').each(function () {
    // do ajax call
      setInterval(loadAdmin(), 10000); // This will call this function in every 10 sec

});
```

Try this. I hope you will found it.